# Refactor the 'factoring' tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

There is a tag [factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factoring).
Its description is:

> "factoring" refers to the mathematical decomposition of integers into their prime factors

But when I click 'learn more' I see:

> operation of decomposing an object (typically an integer) into a product of other objects (typically its prime factors), also called "factorization":

So these two statements are not consistent. Is this tag only for prime factorization or for all factorizations?

I did some research to see how people understand this tag. There was 27 questions tagged [factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factoring) but:

1. Some questions are about 'prime factoring' (for example [Prime Factoring Function in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880023/prime-factoring-function-in-haskell)) so [prime-factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prime-factoring) would be more accurate
2. 3 questions are about Left-Factoring in grammar (for example [How to perform Left-Factoring on a Grammar, make it LL(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578602/how-to-perform-left-factoring-on-a-grammar-make-it-ll1)). So they are mistagged.
3. [factoring out a header and footer in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744078/factoring-out-a-header-and-footer-in-html) is about HTML and has nothing in common with numbers.
4. [Factoring Trinomials With Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098493/factoring-trinomials-with-python) is about factoring trinomials so it is also mistagged.
5. 2 questions have both [factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factoring) and [prime-factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prime-factoring) tag. Is it good?
6. Two questions have both [factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factoring) and [primes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primes) tags but don't have [prime-factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prime-factoring) tag. Isn't it wrong?
7. Few questions have [factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factoring) tag but I don;t know how they are connected with 'factoring'.
8. Only few questions are really about factoring (not only prime factoring).

I made little clean-up and corrected 3 questions. But after complete clean-up there would remain only few questions worth [factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factoring) tag. And maybe there wouldn't remain any.

So should this tag be burninated?

EDIT:
I made some clean-up and there are only 13 not-closed [factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factoring) questions left. Situation now is strange. Tag [factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factoring) has broader meaning than [prime-factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prime-factoring) so there should be more questions tagged [factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factoring) but there is not. Only questions about not-prime factoring are tagged with this tag.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, there's not much difference.

Any time you find two numbers *a* and *b* strictly between 1 and *n*, such that *a* × *b* = *n*, those numbers are proper factors of *n* and you've technically factored *n*.  If you *keep* recursively factoring *a* and *b*, you'll eventually end up with numbers that can't be factored any more; those numbers are called primes, and the ([unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), up to reordering) collection of them that you end up with is called the prime factorization of *n*.

So, basically, the *prime* factorization of a number is what you get if you *completely* factor it, whereas a factorization that contains non-primes is necessarily an incomplete one, since they could be factored further.  That's the only difference there really is.

I'd suggest that [prime-factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prime-factoring) should simply be made a synonym for [factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factoring).  That is, assuming we actually want to keep either of those tags on SO at all.

(I just checked, and [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) does have separate tags for [prime-factorization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prime-factorization) and [factoring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factoring).  That said, in both cases their tag descriptions are somewhat more abstract, and also apply to factoring things other than numbers.  In that sense, the distinction is perhaps justified, especially since not all algebraic structures [have unique prime factorizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain).  I doubt we'll get a lot of questions about such things on SO, though.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that from the wiki summary on [factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factoring) and the description of factoring on the wikipedia page on [factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization) that the author intended it to match the wikipedia page's description.

Tag summary:

> operation of decomposing an object (typically an integer) into a
>   product of other objects (typically its prime factors), also called
>   "factorization": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization

Wikipedia:

> In mathematics, factorization ... or factoring is the decomposition of an object (for
>   example, a number, a polynomial, or a matrix) into a product of other
>   objects, or factors, which when multiplied together give the original.
>   For example, the number 15 factors into primes as 3 × 5, and the
>   polynomial x<sup>2</sup> − 4 factors as (x − 2)(x + 2). In all cases,
>   a product of simpler objects is obtained.

So it seems that the intent is that factoring should encompass more than just prime factoring, but the wiki summary is just bad. However, I agree that in the cases of [grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578602/how-to-perform-left-factoring-on-a-grammar-make-it-ll1) and [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744078/factoring-out-a-header-and-footer-in-html) that those questions were mistagged. In cases that deal with mathematics I say leave them tagged but the wiki summary should be (excuse the pun) summarily edited.

[Trying to find factors of a number in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22130043/3920237) is an example of a question that tries to find all the factors of a number, rather than just the prime factors. Questions that deal with *integer* factorization (known as [prime factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) according to wikipedia) should be tagged as [prime-factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prime-factoring). Questions that have nothing to do with mathematical factoring should be retagged.